# Get minimum timestamp from 3 columns with null

Tags: sql, hive

I have data which has, at `user_id` level 3 timestamps (T1, T2, T3). I wanted to get minimum of this 3 timestamps. I could have wrote a `CASE....WHEN` statement and got the minimum value.

But the problem I am facing is that any of the column can have null values. So how can I overcome the effect of `NULL` while getting minimum value

Below is the data

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id |         T1          |         T2          |         T3          |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2020-01-02 01:38:44 | 2020-01-03 12:38:44 | 2020-01-02 02:48:44 |
|       2 | 2020-01-06 01:38:44 | NULL                | NULL                |
|       3 | NULL                | 2020-01-02 14:38:44 | NULL                |
|       4 | 2020-02-05 13:38:56 | NULL                | 2020-02-02 14:38:56 |
|       5 | 2020-02-04 11:38:56 | 2020-02-05 11:38:56 | NULL                |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Below is the expected result

```
+---------+---------------------+
| user_id |      min_time       |
+---------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2020-01-02 01:38:44 |
|       2 | 2020-01-06 01:38:44 |
|       3 | 2020-01-02 14:38:44 |
|       4 | 2020-02-02 14:38:56 |
|       5 | 2020-02-04 11:38:56 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c61R9K2Z9RrjWzHXwPoDmo/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `least()` with some other magic:

```
select least( coalesce(t1, t2, t3),
              coalesce(t2, t3, t1),
              coalesce(t3, t1, t2)
            )
```

In general, `least()` returns `NULL` if any of the arguments are `NULL`.  However, `coalesce()` will pick out valid arguments if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Hive database handy to try this in, but it holds up in Postgres, which is syntactically pretty close.

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    (SELECT min(v) FROM (VALUES (T1),(T2),(T3)) AS r(v)) as TheMin,
    T1,
    T2,
    T3
FROM 
   mytable;
```

Result:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id |       TheMin        |         T1          |         T2          |         T3          |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2020-01-02 01:38:44 | 2020-01-02 01:38:44 | 2020-01-03 12:38:44 | 2020-01-02 02:48:44 |
|       2 | 2020-01-06 01:38:44 | 2020-01-06 01:38:44 | NULL                | NULL                |
|       3 | 2020-01-02 14:38:44 | NULL                | 2020-01-02 14:38:44 | NULL                |
|       4 | 2020-02-02 14:38:56 | 2020-02-05 13:38:56 | NULL                | 2020-02-02 14:38:56 |
|       5 | 2020-02-04 11:38:56 | 2020-02-04 11:38:56 | 2020-02-05 11:38:56 | NULL                |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```